# gradle android plugin variant dependencies: DSL method not found

Tags: android, gradle

I have a multi-flavor project, with flavors called "qa" and "prod". I need to include different versions of a library depending on both the build type and the flavor.

The documentation at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Type-Product-Flavor-Build-Variant suggests that build types and flavors can be combined, using a "flavorBuildCompile" notation. However when I do this I get this error:

```
Error:(88, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'qaDebugCompile()'
```

I'm pretty sure this used to work (in an older version of gradle). Currently using gradle 2.1. I haven't found an explanation if the way to do this has changed.

Note, it works fine if I use "flavorCompile" notation, it only fails when I include the build type as well.

Here is the outline of my build script:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "20"

    ...

    productFlavors {
        qa {
            applicationId "com.myapp.qa"
        }
        prod {
            applicationId "com.myapp.prod"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }

        qa {
            res.srcDirs = ['res_qa']
        }

        prod {
            res.srcDirs = ['res_prod']
        }
    }

}   

...

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    qaCompile 'com.myapp.integration:other_lib:3.0+@aar'  //this is fine

    qaDebugCompile 'com.myapp.integration:mylib_qa:3.0+@aar'   //this fails!
    prodDebugCompile 'com.myapp.integration:mylib_prod:3.0+@aar'
    qaReleaseCompile 'com.myapp.release:mylib_qa:3.0+@aar'
    prodReleaseCompile 'com.myapp.release:mylib_prod:3.0+@aar'

}
```